# my select query is not recognizing a column

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get values for certain columns but it seems like the sql compiler in phpadmin does not recognise it.

```
select count(ciricullum) as 'nooooo_rat',ciricullum 
from surveyresult 
group by ciricullum 
HAVING department ='department1';
```

the error comes as

```
select count(ciricullum) as 'nooooo_rat',ciricullum from surveyresult group by ciricullum HAVING department ='department1' LIMIT 0, 25

#1054 - Unknown column 'department' in 'having clause'
```

i tried using 'department' instead of department and got the same error

Here's the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE surveyresult (
  cust_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  department enum('department1','department2','department3','department4','department5') NOT NULL,
  facilities enum('good','neutral','bad','') NOT NULL,
  faculty enum('good','neutral','bad','') NOT NULL,
  extraciricular enum('good','neutral','bad','') NOT NULL,
  safety enum('good','neutral','bad','') NOT NULL,
  ciricullum enum('good','neutral','bad','') NOT NULL,
  comment varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Comment: Please share the ddl. Why:  We do not know which columns your table has

Comment: There is no mysql compiler within phpmyadmin. The error message comes from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The `having` is for calculated (or not) columns in the `group by`, you can just use `where`

```
select count(ciricullum) as 'nooooo_rat',ciricullum 
from surveyresult 
where department ='department1'
group by ciricullum
```